# 403 forbidden error from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, http-status-code-403

```
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var ingredient = $('#ingredient').val()
  console.log(ingredient)

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key={MY_API_KEY}&q=shredded%20chicken',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: "JsonP",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)

    },
    error: function (xhr, data, error) {
        console.log("error is "+error)
    }
  })
})
```

Hi i just started coding and im trying to create a app to take your ingredients from your fridge and return you back recipe but im getting a 403 forbidden error in my success callback , any ideas why?

Comment: Are you supposed to acces that content ? I mean do you have authorization ?

Comment: Is there `{MY_API_KEY}` in your code, or did you replace it with your API key?

Comment: yes, I'm suppose to be able to access the content @shuju
and I replaced the {MY_API_KEY} with my actual key to see if it would let me access the data, but it wouldn't 

I got it all from here http://food2fork.com/about/api

Comment: Have you tried `'jsonp'`?